# Proving injectiveness by preimage

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, solution-verification

In the first chapter of an introductory topology text, I got stuck at the following exercise.

Define $f:A \to B$. By $f^{-1}$ we denote the preimage operation.

$$\text{If for any $X\subset A$, we have $f^{-1}\big[f[X]\big] = X.$ Then $f$ is injective.}
$$
Pick $y,y' \in f[X]$ such that $y = y'$.

By assumption we can find $x,x' \in X$ such that $y = f(x)$ and $y' = f(x')$.

To prove that $f$ is injective we show that $x = x'$.

By definition we have 
\begin{align*}
x &= f^{-1}(y) \\
  &= f^{-1}(y') \\
  &= x' \ .
\end{align*}

I do not seem to be using the arbitraryness of $X$. It looks like this argument would work even if we just have inclusion of $X$ in $f^{-1}\big[f[X]\big]$.

Comment: For instance the equality $x=f^{-1}(y)$ is wrong, or even senseless.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261157/show-s-f-1fs-for-all-subsets-s-iff-f-is-injective) and the linked questions.

Comment: It is wrong because I should be using curly brackets to indicate that the latter is a set you mean?

Comment: Well, that's to make it have meaning, but even having meaning, it's still wrong because $\{x,x'\}\subseteq f^{-1}\left(\{y\}\right)$.

Comment: Same problem solved [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326436/every-subset-of-a-is-f-saturated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in general $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is a set and can contain more than one element. Example: $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^2,\ x\mapsto x^2$. Then if $y=4$ we have $f^{-1}(\{y\})=f^{-1}(\{4\})=\{-2,2\}$.

In your case you can use $X=f^{-1}(f(X))$ for each subset $X$. Now, if $f(x)=f(x')$, then $\{x\}=f^{-1}(f(\{x\}))=f^{-1}(\{f(x)\})=f^{-1}(\{f(x')\})=f^{-1}(f(\{x'\}))=\{x'\}$ and hence $x=x'$.

Answer (score 1):

You want to show that the preimage consists of at most one point.

Suppose $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$, and let $X=\{x_1\}$.

Then $\{x_1\} = f^{-1} (f ( \{x_1\} ) )$ and since $x_2 \in f^{-1} (f ( \{x_1\} ) )$, this implies $x_2 = x_1$, hence $f$ is injective.

Comment: Isn't it suggestive  to make an assumption for $X$?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: We should prove it for arbitrary $X$. Not only for singleton sets.

Comment: I think you misunderstand your question. It is asking you to prove that $f$ is injective if it satisfies the property $f^{-1}(f(X)) = X$ for **any** $X \subset A$. You are not proving something about $X$, you are proving something about $f$.

Comment: You are trying to prove that if $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$ then you must have $x_1=x_2$. This is what injective means.

Comment: As an aside, all the other answers do exactly what I have done above.

Comment: My point is that your $X$, does not seem arbitrary but our assumption says that ot should be. However I am aware of the fact that we are proving a property about $f$, not $X$.

Comment: You are missing the point. You are given a property the the function $f$ satisfies. We use that property to show that it is injective. The property says that for any $X \subset A$ that we choose we have blah, blah, blah. So, I can choose any specific $X$ I want to prove the property of injectiveness.

Comment: @MusséRedi: In fact, saying that $X=f^{-1}(f(X))$ for any SINGLETON X would be enough to conclude that $f$ is injective, so we don't need to much arbitraryness.

Comment: Eventually we use a singleton to prove injectiveness, as shown in @sranthrop's answer. So you could argue that any singleton will do. I'm just not sure that we can fix $X$, since the statement calls for arbitrary $X$.

Comment: Correction. @copper.hat's second comment makes sense. Indeed, we could just prove it for **any** $X$.

Comment: @MusséRedi: Every single answer here, including the one you accepted, does **exactly** what I have done above.

Comment: My confusion about the arbitraryness has cleared up. Indeed, we all use the same argument.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ isn't injective you can't say that $x = f^{-1}(y)$. The best you have is $x \in f^{-1}(y)$ since the latter object is a set.

Try this.  Your stated hypothesis is that $f^{-1}[f[\{x\}] = \{x\}$.

If $f(x') = f(x)$, then $f(x') \in f[\{x\}]$ so that $x' \in f^{-1}[f[\{x\}]$.

This means $x' \in \{x\}$, implying $x = x'$.